# Including template headers SOLUTION

Tags: c++, templates, include

How bad at programming am I?  Am I a horrible person for this?

```
//templates.cpp
template <typename TYPE> void some_func(int arg1, ...)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Then:

```
//templates.h
#ifndef TEMPLATES_H_INCLUDED
#define TEMPLATES_H_INCLUDED

#include "templates.cpp"
template <typename TYPE> void some_func(int arg1, ...);

#endif
```

Finally:

```
//main.cpp
#include "templates.h"

int main ...
some_func<int>(5);
std::fprintf(stderr, "ZOMG IT WORKT!\n!\n!\n!");
```

It works fine for me.  It seems to solve the endless question a lot of us n00bs have about how to correctly separate .cpp and .h files for templates and then include them without compiler errors.

The line `#include "templates.cpp"` in the templates.h file is basically equivalent to including your declarations and source code all in one file.  But this method nicely separates them, which is what we all seem to be looking for.

Comment: Is this an attempt for FAQ entry? :)

Comment: I'd avoid asking the internet if you're horrible. Don't `#include` .cpp files. Instead define your template inline within the header file and forego the implementation file entirely.

Comment: You're certainly not a horrible person for doing **that**...

Comment: This isn't really saying anything. `#include` is just text replacement; this approach is equivalent to just writing the template definitions in the header directly, which is the completely easy-to-understand advice already often given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Usually the file with the template implementation is given a different extension. For example boost uses `.ipp`, others may use `.inl`.
2. This is not what we really want. What we do want is to separately compile templates' implementation to reduce compile time dependencies.

Comment: Good points, especially number 2.  Thank you - now I know why it is acceptable but not quite the "solution".

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a pretty common approach, except that I think you should put the

```
#include "templates.cpp"
```

at the *end* of the `*.h` rather than at the beginning.

Also, you should still mark the functions as `inline`.

Comment: And that you normally name it `templates_impl.h` or something similar, because `.cpp` files are reserved for compilation units in general.